# How to create my own NSRunLoop in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, nsrunloop

I am doing sample poc to run `EASession` in different runloop instead of using `NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop`. How can i achieve it?

Here my code..

In `ViewController.swift`

```
   let myRef = myClass()
   func viewDidLoad() {
      let status = myRef.openSession()
      print(status)
   }
```

In NSObject Class `myClass.swift`

```
let handler = myHandler()
var isOpened = false
func openSession()-> Bool {
  myHandler._open()

// HERE I WANT TO WAIT TO CHECK THE RESPONSE   ****

  return isOpened
}

func myCustCallBack() {
   isOpened = true
}
```

In `Handler.swift`

```
_open() {
var _accessory: EAAccessory? = nil
        for obj in accessories {
            if obj.protocolStrings.contains("protocolString") {
                _accessory = obj
                break
            }
        }

        if (_accessory != nil) {

            session = EASession(accessory: _accessory!, forProtocol: "protocolString")
            if (session != nil) {
                session?.inputStream?.delegate = self
                session?.inputStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
                session?.inputStream?.open()

                session?.outputStream?.delegate = self
                session?.outputStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
                session?.outputStream?.open()
// HERE WE ARE USING THE NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop() - SO SAME UI THREAD
            }

}
```

In session Callback, when `HasSpaceAvailable` Event triggered writing some data and when `HasBytesAvailable` Event triggered invoking my own delegate method `myCustCallBack()`

**** in this line i have to wait until i read from the ExternalAccessory. How can i do that?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I want to wait to read the response after writing some data to ExternalAccessory. for this only i am trying to run in different runloop.

If it not possible how can i do that?

Comment: unfortunately I have no idea of how ExternalAccessory works